# Find Survivor when n people are sitting in a circle

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

Hi I am across this problem and trying to solve this

Take a second to imagine that you are in a room with 100 chairs arranged in a circle. These chairs are numbered sequentially from One to One Hundred.
At some point in time, the person in chair #1 will be told to leave the room. The person in chair #2 will be skipped, and the person in chair #3 will be told to leave. Next to go is person in chair #6. In other words, 1 person will be skipped initially, and then 2, 3, 4.. and so on. This pattern of skipping will keep going around the circle until there is only one person remaining.. the survivor. Note that the chair is removed when the person leaves the room.Write a program to figure out which chair the survivor is sitting in.

I made good progress but stuck with a issue, after the count reaches 100 and not sure how to iterate from here, can any one help me, this is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindSurvivor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getSurvivorNumber(10));
}

private static int getSurvivorNumber(int numChairs) {
    // Handle bad input
    if (numChairs < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Populate chair array list
    ArrayList<Integer> chairs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numChairs; i++) {
        chairs.add(i + 1);
    }


    int chairIndex = 0;
    int lr =0;
    while (chairs.size() > 1) {
        chairs.remove(lr);
        chairIndex+=1;
        System.out.println(lr+" lr, size "+chairs.size()+" index "+chairIndex);
        if(lr==chairs.size()||lr==chairs.size()-1)
            lr=0;
        lr = lr+chairIndex;
        printChair(chairs);
        System.out.println();
    }

    return chairs.get(0);
}

public static void printChair(ArrayList<Integer> chairs){
    for(int i : chairs){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So on the second iteration, the people in chairs 1, 4, 7, etc. (counting only the remaining chairs) will be kicked out?

Comment: Presumably you want to replace your current `lr` update with something along the lines of `lr = (lr + chairIndex) % chairs.size()`.

Comment: @TedHopp yes people in the remaining chairs will be kicked out based on the count variable..

Comment: No such chair exists. You have dismantled each chair and used it as a weapon. You are the only survivor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 31. Here are three different implementations

```
var lastSurvivor = function(skip, count, chairs) {
    //base case checks to see if there is a lone survivor
    if (chairs.length === 1)
        return chairs[0];
    //remove chairs when they are left/become dead
    chairs.splice(skip, 1);
    //increment the skip count so we know which chair
    //to leave next. 
    skip = (skip + 1 + count) % chairs.length;
    count++;
    //recursive call
    return lastSurvivor(skip, count, chairs);
};

/** TESTS *******************************************************************
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var result = lastSurvivor(0, 0, chairs);
console.log('The lone survivor is located in chair #', result);
// The lone survivor is located in chair # 31




/** ALTERNATE IMPLEMENTATIONS ***********************************************
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Implemenation 2 
-----------------*/

var lastSurvivor2 = function(chairs, skip) {
    skip++;
    if (chairs === 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return ((lastSurvivor2(chairs - 1, skip) + skip - 1) % chairs) + 1;
};

/** Tests 2 *******************************************************************/

var result = lastSurvivor2(100, 0);
console.log('The lone survivor is located in chair #', result);
// The lone survivor is located in chair # 31



/* Implemenation 3 
------------------*/

var chairs2 = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    chairs2.push(i);

var lastSurvivor3 = function(chairs, skip) {
    var count = 0;
    while (chairs.length > 1) {
        chairs.splice(skip, 1);
        skip = (skip + 1 + count) % chairs.length;
        count++;
    }
    return chairs[0];
};

/** Tests 3 *******************************************************************/

var result = lastSurvivor3(chairs2, 0);
console.log('The lone survivor is located in chair #', result);
// The lone survivor is located in chair # 31
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your removal pattern is but I'd probably implement this as a circular linked list where the 100th seat holder will connect back to the 1st seat holder.  If you use an array, you will have to worry about re-organizing the seats after every removal.

Comment: Using a circular linked list is simple but not efficient (taking _O(mn)_, quadratic time). The rank tree solution solves in _O(n log n)_.

Comment: @gknicker here m=2 (every other person is eliminated), so this suggest gives a linear-time solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your step is incremental you can you use the following code:

```
    int cur = 0;
    int step = 1;
    while (chairs.size() > 1) {
        chairs.remove(cur);
        cur += ++step;
        cur %= chairs.size();
    }
    return chairs.get(0);
```

If your step is fixed to 1 then based on explanation provided by @Jarlax you can solve the problem with one-line of code in O(log n) time:

```
//for long values
public static long remaining(long numChairs) {
    return (numChairs << 1) - (long)Math.pow(2,Long.SIZE - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(numChairs));
}

//for BigInteger values
public static BigInteger remaining(BigInteger numChairs) {
    return numChairs.shiftLeft(1).subtract(new BigInteger("2").pow(numChairs.bitLength()));
}
```

However, if you stick with ArrayLists no extra variables are required to your code. Always remove the first element and remove-then-add the next at the end of the list. This is however O(n).

```
    while (chairs.size() > 1) {
        chairs.remove(0);
        chairs.add(chairs.remove(0));
    }
    return chairs.get(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution, but its not the correct solution for that question because in your solution there is only one skip, but the skip should be in incremental order like 1,2,3,4...

Comment: Solution for incremental step is also added. *It was not clear that this was a requirement though, that's why all of us answered based on a fixed step.

Answer (score 0):

There is elegant analytical solution:

Let's change numbering of people: #2 -> #1, #3 -> #2, ..., #1 -> #100 (in the end we just need to substract 1 to "fix" the result). Now first person remains instead or leaving. Suppose that there is only 64 people in circle. It's easy to see that after first elimination pass 32 people  in circle will remain and numbering will start again from #1. So in the end only #1 will remain.

We have 100 people. After 36 people will leave the circle we will end up with 64 people - and we know how to solve this. For each person that leaves the room one person remains, so circle with 64 people will start from 1 + 2*36 = #73 (new #1). Because of changing indexes on first step final answer will be #72.

In general case res = 2*(N - closest_smaller_pow_2) = 2*N - closest_larger_pow_2. The code is trivial:

```
public static long remaining(long total) {
    long pow2 = 1;
    while (pow2 < total) {
        pow2 *= 2;
    }
    return 2*total - pow2;
}
```

Also this algorithm has O(log(N)) complexity instead of O(N), so it's possible to calculate function for huge inputs (it can be easily adapted to use BigInteger instead of long).

Comment: Small comment. To make code exactly as in description: condition in while loop should be `pow2 <= total` and before returning there should be `if (result == 0) result += total`. However provided version is equivalent and is a bit simpler.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, but your solution is valid if we are skipping only one person, but here we should skip persons in incremental order..

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume the chairs are numbered from 0. We'll switch the numbering back at the end -- but usually things are simpler when items are enumerated from 0 rather than 1.

Now, if you've got n people and you start eliminating at chair x (x is 0 or 1) then in a single pass through you're going to eliminate half the people. Then you've got a problem of roughly half the size (possibly plus one), and if you solve that, you can construct the solution to the original problem by multiplying that sub-result by 2 and maybe adding one.

To code this, it's simply a matter of getting the 4 cases (n odd or even vs x 0 or 1) right. Here's a version that gets the 4 cases right by using bitwise trickery.

```
public static long j2(long n, long x) {
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    return j2(n/2 + (n&x), (n&1)^x) + 1-x;
}
```

A solution with chairs numbered from 1 and without the extra argument can now be written:

```
public static long remaining(long n) {
    return 1 + j2(n, 0);
}
```

This runs in O(log n) time and uses O(log n) memory.